# Plot Pandas row values based on descending order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I've got a dataframe with 1000 rows and a `Total` row at the bottom:

```
df.tail()

        22   88   24   11   12  21  99  61  13  44  65  64  62  89  220  63
996      1    2    2    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0   0
997      1    1    0    3    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0   0
998      1    0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0   0
999      0    0    0    1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0   0
Total  289  601  304  360  115  31  54  14  33  13  10  14  11   2   13   8
```

I'd like to plot the `Total` row in descending order, or even sort the dataframe columns in descending order based on `df.loc['Total']`.

Currently I've got:

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Total'], axis=0, ascendin=False)
sorted_plot = df_sorted.loc['Total'].plot(kind='bar', title ="Codes", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

However, I'm getting a KeyError for `Total`.

I've found resources to sort by columns but not by a row.

Answer (score 2):

Change `axis=0` to `axis=1`, because you are sorting columns, not rows.